# Laravel eager loading SQL?

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have the following code for retrieving both Reservation and ReservationDetail using eager loading:

```
$reservationsDetail = ReservationDetail::with('reservation')
            ->whereDate('date_res', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
            ->toSql();

dd($reservationsDetail);
```

Which prints this SQL query on browser:

```
select * from `tbl_reservation_detail` where date(`date_res`) = ?
```

Shouldn't it be showing the retrieval for the Reservation table as well (tbl_reservation)? How can I make sure it's actually retrieving both (i.e. eager loading is working as expected)?

Btw, I have a BelongsTo relationship on ReservationDetail model:

```
public function reservation(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Reservation', 'id_reservation');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving the relationship is a second query. You can make sure it works fine by installing the [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). It shows all queries, that were executed. `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` might also help you out.

Comment: You are right, it does a second query with an IN statement on tbl_reservation. Nice package btw, thanks.

Comment: No problem. Absolutely, I guess you'll use the package in every project now.